# Implementation Spring Security in ActiveMQ

Tags: spring, security, activemq-classic

i have embedded activemq broker in spring boot application, current solution for authentication is SimpleAuthentication plugin, but i need some solution that use spring security for activemq authentication. I can't find what i need, did someone know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ leverages Apache Shiro for advanced security configurations.
You always write [your own](http://www.javabeat.net/building-a-custom-security-plugin-in-activemq/) authentication plugin that uses Spring security

Comment: Hi, i know for apache shiro... But i asked for Spring Security, not for other solutions.

Comment: Yes, and I stated that you can write your own JAAS plugin to leverage the part of Spring Security you are using. Link provided in the answer. It should not be that much work. As far as I know, there are no public or generic plugins to use for Spring Security integration.